# My app freezes at first launch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Every time I run my app on my iPhone through XCode it freezes, it doesn't respond, to make it work I hit stop button and then launch it from my iPhone and it works only I'm having problem with launching it from XCode using build&run, here's what happen in the debugger when the app freezes:

```
-------
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/libstatusbar.dylib (file not found).
unable to read unknown load command 0x25
unable to read unknown load command 0x26
Program received signal:  “SIGUSR1”.
-------
```

Any idea how to sort this out?

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall mobilesubstrate or the plugin causing that, libstatusvar.dylib... Check Cydia.

Comment: i could only find package called "mobile substrate" in cydia, and removing it will cause the system to crash, i tried another phone and works without issues, thanks !

Comment: You can always restore, that will remove the jailbreak.